# Add classes to a collection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class called "Transport":

```
Public Frequency As Double
Public SourceDest As String
```

Now, I want to read out some cells in Excel and fill a collection with these objects of that class.

Collection:

```
Dim JobList As New Collection
```

Sub:

```
Dim tmp As New Transport

For i = 1 To 20
    tmp.Frequency = Round(Frequencies(i), 5)
    tmp.SourceDest = Jobs(i)
    JobList.Add tmp
Next
```

Unfortunately, it just adds the same class 20 times, but I want different classes. How can I solve this?

In general, I am new to VBA and all I want is to read two columns in a table, put the "pairs" together (like so: `{Double, String}`) in a kind of list `{Double, String},{Double, String}, ...`. I tried types before, but apparently they can't be stored in collections, so I chose classes.

Comment: I don't know how many times you want to add the class, but the For Loop is set to run 20 times. You could increase the loop duration to your required number of loops

Comment: I think the OP is saying that there is no change in the contents of the created class e.g. the frequency. The same "class" is added 20 times.

Comment: I should explain this better. What I want is to add a range of cells (in my case, for now, 20). They are not all the same, but when I do my approach it only adds the same class 20 times to the collection. It does not construct a new one each loop.

Comment: it is at the top of my question. it only consists of these two attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a different **object** of the class each time you loop, you have to 'tell' VBA to create it **inside** the loop.
In line 4 a new **instance** of Transport Class is created in each loop

```
Dim tmp As Transport

For i = 1 To 20
    Set tmp = New Transport
    tmp.Frequency = Round(Frequencies(i), 5)
    tmp.SourceDest = Jobs(i)
    JobList.Add tmp
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked perfectly. As a note, I had it inside the loop before but it still did not work - even when debugging I noticed that it never jumped back. My guess is that you need the keyword `set` insteam of `dim`.

Comment: @mneumann   `Dim` is a one time decleration inside a block of code. It doesnt metter were you put it because VBA treats it as 1 block of code. Whilest `New` actually creates a new **Instance** of the class